# Wait for function to exit before continuing foreach loop in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, function, wait, exit, scriptblock

I have a list of functions that get called in loop `$listoffunctions`.
Some are run in RunspacePool (multithread) while others run in the main thread. The ones that run in main thread are forms with buttons.

I need the ones that run in the main thread (interactive forms) to finish before continuing the foreach loop with other functions in list.

`$listoffunctions` contains strings of function names with parameters sometimes like `RichTextDocumentNewContext -Show` and `UseStoreOpenWith -Hide` and `PostActions`.

`$WinAPIList` contains a list of function names that call up a form with buttons (form XAML and buttons) for user to interact with. So it contains function names like `ScheduledTasks -Disable` and `ScheduledTasks -Enable`. Foreach loop should wait for the user to finish interacting with this form completely and its background commands to finish.

```
foreach ($singlefunction in $listoffunctions)
{
    # PowerShell
    $PowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create() 
    $PowerShell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    
    # These functions run in main thread which names are found in WinAPIList
    if ($WinAPIList -contains $singlefunction){
        [void]$PowerShell.AddScript({Write-Output "Main Thread Run"})

        # This runs the function but I need it to wait for it to end before continue foreach loop   
        #$sb = [scriptblock]::Create($singlefunction)
        #& $sb
        
        # This does not work
        Start-Job -Name Job1 -ScriptBlock {$singlefunction}
        Wait-Job -Name Job1
        
    }
    # These function are run in the RunspacePool (Multithread)
    else{
        # Add script (function) to run

        [void]$PowerShell.AddScript($singlefunction)
    }
}
```

This does not work

```
# This does not work
Start-Job -Name Job1 -ScriptBlock {$singlefunction}
Wait-Job -Name Job1
```

Comment: We dont know what `$listoffunctions` or `$WinAPIList` are. Better provide a minimal reproducible example of the issue instead of making us guess things

Comment: Sorry. I added more information. Thank you so much Santiago Squarzon

Comment: `& ([scriptblock]::Create($singlefunction))` should run _synchronously_ - is that not what you want, or does the function itself launch something _asynchronously_? Unless your functions are in auto-loading modules, `Start-Job` won't see them; if they are, you'd need to use `Start-Job ([scriptblock]::Create($singlefunction))`, but that is just a much less efficient way of invoking them, compared to direct invocation.

Comment: Thanks for this information. It is running synchronously. I thought is wasn't. heheh. My bad observation.